# How to access files on a different domain in C#

Tags: c#, dns

I need a way to acccess files on a fileshare from a different domain from my own? for example, I have here is an application that exists on a sever in Domain1 and this application needs to retrieve files from a server on Domain2.

Any ideas...

Answer (score 1):

Does this help you in the right direction? I assume it's what your asking...

[Map a Network Drive From Code for Cross-Domain File Copy.](http://codebetter.com/blogs/brendan.tompkins/archive/2004/09/24/26730.aspx)

The CodeProject link given on the site also gives the source code for downloading.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar issue and executing

```
net use \\machine.otherdomain myusername /USER:password
```

as part of the user's network logon was a solution for us.
This is obviously not perfect but for our environment it was sufficient.